# Unknown PLL case

Tags: rubiks-cube

I'm learning CFOP's Permutation of the Last Layer Algorithms. This hasn't appeared in any PLL list I've seen so far. Really not sure how to search for this/what's the alg to finish the cube. To get to the case from a solved cube, just do Z perm and T perm

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the A perm. Just a bit hard to see if edge pieces was not color-aligned.